# Derived classes derived traits

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Here is the diagram:
[image: class hierarchy]

Class `B` has some group of methods `trait1`.
Class `B1` and `C1` has similar group of methods `trait2`.
`trait2` is derived from `trait1`.

**How can I implement this?** I was going to move all of these `trait`s methods out from the main hierarchy into some separate one. Then derive `B`, `B1` and `C1` from appropriate trait. But then I realized that there would be a problem with inheriting `B1` from `B` because `B1` would have `trait1` too.

Now I think I can have some field of type, say, `TraitBase`, and initiate it with appropriate ctor of type either `trait1` or `trait2`. But I don't like the idea that I should have a field so my class has some special behaviour. May be there is another solution? Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I mean class `B` has some feature, which is derived in `B1`. `C1` should have the feature, which class `B1` has.

```
class B
{
   virtual foo1();
   virtual foo2();


   virtual trait_method1(); //implementation 1
   virtual trait_method2(); //implementation 1
};

class B1 : public B
{
   virtual foo1();
   virtual foo2();


   virtual trait_method1(); //implementation 2
   virtual trait_method2(); //implementation 2
};

class C1 : public C
{
   virtual bar1();
   virtual bar2();


   trait_method1(); //implementation 2
   trait_method2(); //implementation 2
};
```

Comment: Can you express the idea in pseudo-code? I do not understand what 'group of methods' is.

Comment: I think you should add more information.

Comment: Another question: trait1 and trait2 have same function name but different implementations, or different function names?

Comment: trait1 and trait2 have same functions name but different implementations

Comment: Maybe a good old violation of 'is a' (In terms of modelling data a square is no rectangle)

Comment: I updated the post. Ask more questions if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem may be solved by virtually inheriting from trait1:

`class trait2 : virtual public trait1{}
class B : public A, virtual public trait1{}
class B1 : public B, public trait2{}
class C1 : public C, public trait2{}`

However, this design only makes sense if class trait1 is stateless. If not, consider different designs, maybe Bridge pattern.

Comment: "trait"s are methods not classes.

Comment: @Lasokoz: OP wrote: "I was going to move all of these traits methods out from the main hierarchy into some separate one. Then derive B, B1 and C1 from appropriate trait.". He wanted to make trait a class.

Comment: @user2198121: I have edited the answer to fix the typo and included class C1

Comment: I cannot suggest edit: try to indent every code line with four spaces for better readability.

Comment: @Eugene, Thank you for the solution. How do you think, can I make abstract `trait` class, then virtually derive it with `trait1` like this http://pastebin.com/SfHfR8ad to exclude surplus virtual inheritance?
Are there any pitfalls?

Comment: @user2198121: No, this way B1 still has 2 instances of trait1. I also think your native language is Russian :).

Comment: @Eugene, I suppose, it is not because my English is auful =)